# Get ranges of dataframe given an input value (i.e. 1 returns df[1:10,])

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe df, and I want to create a function in R that returns ranges of 10 entries of the dataframe given an input number. That is:

```
    If input number is equal to 1, the function returns df[1:10,]

    If input number is equal to 2, the function returns df[11:20,]

    If input number is equal to 3, the function returns df[21:30,]

    ...
```

Like they were pages: page 1 shows ten entries, page 2 shows next ten entries, and so on.

Note:

1. if there're no more "ten entries" to return, the function should return all what's left in the dataframe
2. the lenght of the dataframe is not fixed (i.e. the function asks for the df to use and the "page" to return).

It looks pretty simple to implement but I cannot figure out how to do it in a proper and fast way.

**Edit**

I meant returning the rows not columns, sorry. Just edited. But @Freakazoid solution does more or less the trick, just changing the ncol by nrow (see his solution below)

Comment: it would be more helpful if you provide a sample of your data with ``dput(data)``

Comment: what if dataframe has 40 rows and it asks for 7th page to display? What would be the output in that case?

Comment: It's very likely imo that you want to select rows and not columns, as your syntax seems to suggest. However, consider that the lower limit is `1+(x-1)*10` and the upper limit is just `10*x` (`x` is the input number).

Comment: Pls give some feedback to the answers. Did something helped or do you have thurder questions? Thx!

Comment: Thanks for all your feedback. Indeed, as I mentioned in the edited question, @Freakazoid does perfectly the trick with a few modifications to adapt it to rows instead of columns (my mistake in the initial question). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following function does the trick:

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(1020), nrow=54, ncol=3))

batch_df <- function(df, batch_part) {
  nbr_row <- nrow(df)
  batch_size <- 10
  nbr_of_batchs <- as.integer(nbr_row/batch_size)
  last_batch_size <- (nbr_row - nbr_of_batchs*batch_size) 

  batch_indizes <- c(rep(1:nbr_of_batchs, each=batch_size), 
                     rep(nbr_of_batchs+1, last_batch_size))

  if(all(batch_part %in% batch_indizes)) {
    row_index <- which(batch_indizes %in% c(batch_part))
    ret_df <- df[ row_index,]
  } else {
    ret_df <- data.frame()
  }
  return(ret_df)
}

batch_df(df, 3)
```

The function first defines indices for rows. With these indices the function will search for the batch_part you want to select. 
The function can not only take a single number; it can be a vector given where you can select multiple batch parts at once.

Output:

```
       X1          X2         X3
21  0.7168950  0.88057886  0.1659177
22 -1.0560819 -0.53230247 -0.4204708
23  0.4835649 -1.43453719  0.1563253
24  0.1266011  1.22149179 -0.7924120
25  0.3982262 -0.59821992 -1.1645105
26 -0.4809448  0.42533877  0.2359328
27 -0.1530060 -0.23762552  0.9832919
28  0.8808083 -0.06004995 -1.0810818
29 -0.2924377 -1.23812802 -0.9057353
30 -0.2420152 -0.52037258  0.7406486
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution does the trick! I meant rows not columns (my mistake, sorry), but the solution is the same just changing the nrow by ncol. And just  inside the 'batch_indizes' variable, the 'each' parameter must be 'each = batch_size'

Answer (score 1):

Given input number `i`, try

```
j <- i * 10
max <- pmin(j, nrow(df))
df[(j-9):max, ]
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution also works, although it's true that Freakazoid solution handles better the last subset of the dataframe in case it's smaller than 10. And also takes into account the size of the df, so it returns an empty dataframe instead of a df filled of NAs. Of course, that's for my particular case that I needed with these requirements, but for sure in other cases your solution would work perfectly!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the last page is handled correctly and does not return NA rows. Am I mistaken? I will concede that my solution fails when there are no valid rows in the domain, and that the other answer handles that better.